# new Bitmap(MemoryStream ms) returns upside-down image

Tags: c#, bitmap, memorystream

I have two byte[] - representations of bitmap - one from bitmap.save(ms), ms.toarray, and the other from a bunch of other functions. According to my eyes that witnessed output of Watch windows, these two byte arrays are exactly equal. SequenceEquals() call says the same. Here's the code:

```
public void Debug(Bitmap b){
  DrawImage(viewIn, b);
  byte[] t1 = BmpConv.GetAllData(b);
  byte[] t2 = BmpConv.ConcatBytes(BmpConv.GetHeaderData(b), BmpConv.GetColorData(b));
  var eq = t1.SequenceEqual(t2); // returns true
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(t2);
  DrawImage(viewOut, new Bitmap(ms));
}
```

The problem is: 
If memorystream is created using t1 array, image is okay.
If memorystream is created using t2 array, image is upside-down.
What.
Can someone tell me what is going on? Right now i am going to believe in ghosts and just put a crutch to invert bitmaps in some places of my code.

---

upd2: Resolved. It turned out to be a bug in my GetColorData. Unfortunately, my test bitmap was symmetrical, so i was not able to see that copying via Marshall.Copy and Bitmap.Save copies rows in different order.

Comment: Can you post a runnable piece of code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I posted a BmpConv class source code. You need any bitmap in memory and a picturebox to output your image to. (DrawImage, if stripped of all additional logic, is just a g.DrawImage(bmp))